# "If" with "and" in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, function

I am using an if condition in a java script function, although I have checked and && is used in java scripts but somehow it's not working. Can anyone suggest, what could be wrong here:

```
if(slugs[i].match("^{{") && slugs[i].match("}}$"))
{
    alert(slugs[i] + "YES!");
}
```

while nested if checks are working fine.

```
if(slugs[i].match("^{{"))
{
    if(slugs[i].match("}}$"))
    {
        alert(slugs[i] + "YES!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex in JavaScript are objects with syntax `/regex/`, not strings.

Comment: seems working to me:
`a = "{{a}}"; if (a.match("^{{") && a.match("}}$")) { console.log("1"); }`

Comment: It works because it will try to do `new RegExp('^{{')`, but `{` will have to be double escaped or use a literal regex `/^\{\{/`

Comment: JavaScript, not java script.

Comment: @mishik: Also browsers are smart, but technically brackets should be escaped.

Comment: @elclanrs, yes, but only when using `/.../` syntax, while with simple "..." they are fine.

Comment: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/XEzxs/1/) your both condition is working there might be other problem

Comment: @mishik: AFAIK when you use a string as regex you have to double escape like `"^\\{\\{"`

Comment: @elclanrs: curly brackets don't need to be escaped in general, and the opening or the closing bracket must be escaped on an only case for disambiguation when you write something like that, with only digits inside: `{123\}` or `\{123}` but not `{1b3}` or `{abc}` or `{}` (it's the same with php, ruby, .net)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Recommended, but not needed I guess... JSLint will surely bug you about it: http://jsbin.com/ugizah/1/edit

Comment: @elclanrs: sorry but no bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: You should use a check like `slugs[i].match(/^\{\{.*\}\}$/)`

On the other hand [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2k3gb/2/) shows that everything works as expected. The problem might be somewhere else

```
var slugs = ['{{slug}}'];
var i = 0;
// your example #1
if(slugs[i].match("^\{\{") && slugs[i].match("\}\}$"))
{
    alert(slugs[i] + "YES!");
}
// your example #2
if(slugs[i].match("^\{\{"))
{
    if(slugs[i].match("\}\}$"))
    {
        alert(slugs[i] + "YES!");
    }
}

// corrected to use a single regex to accomplish the same thing
if(slugs[i].match(/^\{\{.*\}\}$/))
{
    alert(slugs[i] + "YES!");
}
```

Comment: No, testing for thruthiness is fine - it returns `null` when not matching. Getting its `length` property will break the script.

Answer (score 1):

You are not making the regexp properly, although quotes work in some cases.

[match() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Try this

```
if(slugs[i].match(/^{{/) && slugs[i].match(/}}$/))
{
    alert(slugs[i] + "YES!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`match` will return `null` if pattern not found, Try this:

```
if (slugs[i].match("^{{") !== null && slugs[i].match("}}$") !== null)
{
    alert(slugs[i] + "YES!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is simply to determine whether there is a match then you're better using `.test()` rather than `.match()`. `.match` will return an array, or `null`, while `.test()` will return a boolean. This requires a different syntax:

Try this:

```
if (/^{{/.test(slugs[i]) && /}}$/.test(slugs[i])) {
{
  alert(slugs[i] + "YES!");
}
```

Comment: Basically using `test` is the right approach, but this doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks. I was a little hasty. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the nested `if`s and [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) `&&`, your mistake must be elsewhere.

Anyway, I'd suggest using [regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression) instead of the strings which are converted to regexes each time, and to call the boolean [`test` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of making matches:

```
if (/^\{\{/.test(slugs[i]) && /\}\}$/.test(slugs[i]))
    alert(slugs[i]+" YES!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge 2 conditions..

```
if(x = slugs[i].match(/^{{(.+)}}$/)){
  alert(x[1]+"YES!");
}
```

Comment: But not like this please. Yours doesn't match `"{{}}"`, the capturing group is unnecessary and you've forgot to escape the braces.

Comment: @Bergi I understand that he wants to alert something inside double braces.